# Scale (or stretch) Leaflet map tiles to look bigger

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet

I am using leaflet and I am using the same tile provider as the main openstreetmap's website (`http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`). However, leaflet seems to fit many more tiles in 1 screen than openstreetmap. This results in the icons been super small, and I can barely read the letters in a 1080p monitor. Look at this screenshot:

[image: 1]

That is the same exact tile in openstreetmap's website and my website.

This is the tile:

[image: 2]

How can I scale (or stretch) the map tiles, so that my tiles look bigger ? It seems like Openstreetmap doubles scales their tiles by 200%. Which means that the 256x256 image ocupies a space of 512x512 in the actual website.

Comment: You would probably be interested in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040494/html-css-js-street-labels-in-leaflet-too-small/37043490#37043490

Comment: @ghybs I have seen this, that is not what I am trying to do. My tiles are mapped correctly. I just want to stretch them.

Comment: From what I see, @ghybs's solution will do exactly what you want: double the apparent size of map tiles. Also do check the [pixel ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) of your browsers/webpages.

Comment: @IvanSanchez No. That  pixel x pixel is the original .png file's size... If I change to 512 I don't see the map at all. `pixel ratio` will change the whole page though. Not just the map. Right ?

Comment: As @ghybs's solution points out, change `tileSize` **and** `zoomOffset`. The pixel ratio *might* be the cause why you're seeing tile sizes differently in the first place and is worth being checked.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I have tried all of that before ghybs mentioned that question. I have already seen this.